# How to fix migrations for an app with existing schema while not touching other apps?

Tags: django, django-migrations

*Django 1.9.7, db.sqlite3 as DB*

I have a Django project with several apps. For app "A", I had migrations, but I deleted them by accident and pushed to the remote git. Also, a lot of new stuff for other apps was pushed to the git during the day. Other apps don't depend on the "A" app models.

Everything worked until I decided to add a new field to the model of the "A" app. I got `OperationalError: no such column:` error. I tried to make initial migrations for the app "A" `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`. I got new migrations but I still have the `OperationalError: no such column:`.

How to fix "A" app migrations without affecting other apps migrations?

Comment: Can you not just revert to a previous commit?

Comment: @Sayse Other guys that develop other apps inside this project added already some new stuff and did some merges. Is it possible to fix the migrations without git revert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `git` point of view, you can do `revert` to previous commit.

```
git revert sha #commit sha of the last commit
```

**OR**

```
git reset --hard HEAD~n #n how many commits to remove.
git push --force
```

Fixing through django(possible if you didn't add any migrations later.),

```
python manage.py makemigrations APP_A --empty
python manage.py makemigrations APP_A 
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Comment: Other guys that develop other apps inside this project added already some new stuff and did some merges. Is it possible to fix the migrations without git revert?

Comment: I'll try Django way

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `git revert` didn't help me. In the end, I solved the problem by executing the following steps:

1.Manually delete all tables related to the "A" app in db.sqlite3.

2.Create new migrations and db.sqlite3 tables from existing schema:

```
python manage.py makemigrations A --empty
python manage.py makemigrations A
python manage.py migrate
```

3.Dump the tables data back into db.sqlite3 from a backup:

```
sqlite3 ~/Backup/A/db.sqlite3 ".dump table_name" | grep -v "CREATE" | sqlite3 db.sqlite3
```